# Elegant non-const reference to a QVariantMap node?

Tags: c++, json, qt

Basically I need to generate a nested QVariantMap. (Think JSON):

```
{ "foo" : 1, "bar" : { "node" : 0 } }
```

I do this in Qt this way:

```
QVariantMap r, r_bar;

r["foo"] = QVariant(1);
r_bar["node"] = QVariant(0);

r["bar"] = r_bar;
```

Which is very inconvenient for large nested structures. Is there an elegant way of doing this, such as this (fake syntax)?:

```
r["foo"] = QVariant(1);
r["bar"]["node"] = QVariant(0);
```

I cannot do this:

```
r["foo"].toMap()["node"] = QVariant(0)
```

because all "toSomething" functions of QVariant return a copy of the object, not a reference to it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I usually just create my own wrapper class around Map and Variant to accomplish this. So the idea is to not to insert other map instances as variants, but handle them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use only one map like this:

```
r["foo"] = QVariant(1);
r["bar/node"] = QVariant(0);
```

The only problem with this approach is that you lose the ability to iterate sub maps. There is no easy way to find out the subnodes of the "bar" node.